# How to Update the Many Sides in One to Many Relationship in JPA?

Tags: java, jpa

JPA question, I want to update the many side in the one to many relationship, for example I have purchase order which has a lot of item. Next I want to update the items, discounts or misc charges in one particular po... right now the only working solution for me is like this.... it requires 2 commits, first delete all of the many sides first, then construct the purchase order again and commit again... is this the only solution, without the first commit, it fails because it said like... "the item was already in the database, if I attached the same item to the po" although I used remove before I commited in the end...

```
Environment.getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();

for (POItem _item: po.getPOItems()) {

Environment.getEntityManager().remove(_item);

}


for (PODiscount _disc : po.getDiscounts()) {

Environment.getEntityManager().remove(_disc);

}


for (POMiscCharge _misc : po.getMiscCharges()) {

Environment.getEntityManager().remove(_misc);

}

Environment.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();


Environment.getEntityManager().getTransaction().begin();
// construct the purchase order again in here
po.setItems(newItems);
po.setDiscounts(newDiscounts);
po.setMiscCharges(newMiscCharges);

Environment.getEntityManager().getTransaction().commit();
```